# How to use Gradle behind a firewall without setting a password, just a user?

Tags: grails, gradle

Title says it all, I'm currently using a file in my '.gradle' directory called 'gradle.properties' to set `systempProp.http.proxy*` stuff.  I've noticed that with Grails you don't need to set a `http.proxy.proxyPassword` just the `http.proxHost`, `http.proxyPort`, and `http.proxyUser` in the '.grails\ProxySettings.groovy' file.

Is there some systemProp/configuration I can use so I don't need to put my password in plaintext using Gradle?

Comment: I would assume that if the proxy required a password it would force grails to have one too. In the question text I mentioned that I didn't have to set the proxy password in the '.grails\ProxySettings.groovy' file.  However I think grails now uses a different proxy config so..  The answer basically confirms my other research, I'll mark your answer as the solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle cannot eliminate the need for a password, if your proxy requires it. If you however do not want to check your password into code (clearly, that is a stupid thing to do :) ), you should use environment variables to hide it.

You can either set the env variable: `http.proxyPassword` to your password, or run gradle with a `-D` parameter:

```
gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=***  -Dhttp.proxyPort=*** -Dhttp.proxyUser=**** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=****
```

Keep in mind that if someone else is building your code without proper env variables set, their build might fail, so remember to include proper instructions.

Also note that there is a different set of properties for https. Oh and if your proxy interferes with SSL certificates, you might also have to import your proxy certificates into your truststore.